# Mattermost web-app connectivity from local(windows machine) to mattermost-server which install on AWS server

Tags: mattermost

I am trying to connect Mattermost web-app from local(windows machine)  to mattermost-server which install on AWS  server.

So my question is...

1. Is it possible?
2. which files are used for API call in Mattermost web app?

Answer (score 1):

Can you expand on your question? Are you attempting to run the Mattermost desktop app locally and connect to a Mattermost server that is running within AWS? If so, this is very possible - just make sure that your server is exposed to the internet, and put its URL into the desktop app.

Comment: yes i am trying to run Mattermost desktop app locally and connect to a Mattermost server that is running within AWS. can you explain how to do this?

Comment: Have you followed this documentation? https://docs.mattermost.com/help/apps/desktop-guide.html#server-management

Have you attempted to connect to your server from a web browser? Chances are, your AWS instance isn't exposed to the internet.